# Android sqlite JOIN not showing data

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I'm working on an Android application with sqlite, LocationsContentProvider.
I'm having some trouble with a JOIN.

This was working fine:

```
    // Returns all the locations from the table
    public Cursor getAllLocations(){            
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_ZOOM, FIELD_ADDRESS } , null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "DB: query complete" + cursor );
        return cursor;
    }
```

And this is not working:

```
    // Return all locations joined with sub map name
    public Cursor getAllLocations(){
        Cursor cursor;
        String query;
        query = "SELECT a._id, a.lat, a.lng, a.sub_map_id, a.zoom, a.address, b._id, b.sub_map FROM locations a" +
                " INNER JOIN sub_map_table b ON a.sub_map_id=b._id";
        Log.d(TAG, "DB: query = \n" + query;
        Log.d(TAG, "DB: query complete" );
        cursor = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Some other details on the database structure:

```
// Fields for locations table
public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID ="_id";
public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";
public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";
public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zoom";
public static final String FIELD_ADDRESS ="address";
public static final String FIELD_SUB_MAP_ID = "sub_map_id";

// Fields for SUB_MAP_TABLE table
public static final String FIELD_SUB_MAP_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String FIELD_SUB_MAP = "sub_map";

//table name, a constant
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";
private static final String SUB_MAP_TABLE = "sub_map_table";

private static final String TAG = null;

//instance variable for SQLiteDatabse
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

//constructor
public LocationsDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
    this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
}

/** This is a callback method, invoked when the method getReadableDatabase() / getWritableDatabase() is called
    * provided the database does not exists
    * */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table_locations =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                                         FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                                         FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
                                         FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
                                         FIELD_ZOOM + " text , " +
                                         FIELD_ADDRESS + " text , " +
                                         FIELD_SUB_MAP_ID + " integer " +
                                         " ) ";

        String create_table_submap = "create table " + SUB_MAP_TABLE + " ( " +
                                    FIELD_SUB_MAP_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                                    FIELD_SUB_MAP + " text " +
                                    " ) ";

        db.execSQL(create_table_locations);
        db.execSQL(create_table_submap);
```

Been looking at this for the entire day and I can't figure out what's wrong. Please advise me.
Nothing seems to be sent through? Or if it is sent through, it isn't being captured.

Comment: Is there some error in your logcat? If it is an invalid query, SQLite will tell you so. If not, your query might just have 0 results and we couldn't answer you that without knowing your database data and structure.

Comment: Is `DATABASE_TABLE`=`"locations"`? And every `FIELD_`* match `"a._`*`"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 'nothing seems to be sent through', I take it that you are not experiencing an error and it is simply that your query returns no data?

If that is the case, then the issue may be with your data. Any rows in 'location' where sub_map_id IS NULL will fail the join and not be returned. Likewise, any rows where sub_map_id does not have a matching entry of _id in sub_map_table will not be returned.

If you use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, then you will get all the rows from 'location'. However where the join to sub_map_table fails, the values returned for b._id and b.sub_map will be NULL.

In addition, you have duplicate column names in your results set, i.e. a._id and b._id will both return with the column name '_id' which will cause problems if you try to reference them from the cursor. You can use AS to distinguish them and give them a unique name in the results, e.g:

```
SELECT a._id AS a_id, b._id AS b_id
```

Comment: Thanks indeed it was the INNER JOIN giving the problem. I've changed it to LEFT JOIN and it works fine. Output with INNER JOIN was empty. However using a.id AS a_id will throw me an error "column '_id' does not exist. Am trying to figure out if I should leave it as it is.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. If you use a cursor in an adapter, it must have a column named "_id" within in. So I suggest just using AS on b._id.